# Complex object as request param and snake case not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have this API:

```
@GetMapping
Page<Report> get(Report report, Pageable pageable) {
    return repository.findAll(Example.of(report), pageable);
}
```

And this model:

```
public class Report {
    private String reporterId;
    // more fields
```

The problem is, if I request like this:

```
/search?reporterId=123
```

It works. But if I try like this:

```
/search?reporter_id=123
```

It does **not** work. I'd like both working, but if not possible at least the snake_case.

I have `spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy: SNAKE_CASE` set.

---

PS: I tried `@JsonProperty("reporter_id")` on the field but doesn't work either.

Comment: Jackson is used for (de)serialization when sending a request with a body to the server it is not used for parameter binding. So setting the `spring.jackson` properties for binding use pretty much a futile attempt. Spring by default will bind using request parameter names and find the corresponding property on the object. If you want to change this you would have to change the internals of Spring. The easiest is probably to use URL rewriting and transform the `reporter_id` into `reporterId` before passing it to the controller.

Comment: @M.Deinum how can I use a URL rewriting?

Comment: Google can help you there, use something like a [`UrlRewriteFilter`](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)